# Fullcalendar 1.5.4 - How can I remove one event from a series?

Tags: fullcalendar

Fullcalendar - How can I remove one event from a series?
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

little more information would be helpful but still you must be returning an unique id when rendering the calender.

i would suggest you catch the id via `eventRender` method and remove it.
following is how i achieved it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                theme: true,
                eventRender: function(event,element) {
                    if(event.id=="3")
                    {
                        element.remove();
                    }

                },

                eventSources: [
                    {
                        url: "jsonarray.jsp",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        error: function() {
                            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        }

                    }
                ]

            });
        });
```

Comment: I guess you remove event during rendering from data source. I want to remove already rendered event (created by user and not yet saved). Maybe I could use rerender method and then your approach.

Comment: like i said a little more info would fetch you more replies still if you haven't saved the events created by the user ,re rendering them would remove them altogether solving your problem.